# Rails 4 - Adding Image attributes in .scss prevents image from loading

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

In my Rails 4 project I was able to load an image from .scss with the following:

```
background-image: url(/assets/intro-bg.jpg);
```

However when I need to add the following attributes I can't get the image to load:

```
background-image: url(/assets/intro-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
```

Comment: A CSS validator would have caught this problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to just use `background` if you're specifying more than just the image:

```
background: url(/assets/intro-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
```